# Javascript results in URL?

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

I am using the following javascript code that spits out a date in the format of mmddyy. Is there a way to add the results to a URL link, so that it spits out:

`<a href="http://test.com/mmddyy.html">test
    </a>`

JS code I am using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatDate(d) {
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        year = year.toString().substr(2, 2);
        month = month + 1;
        month = month + "";

        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = day + "";
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return month + day + year;
    }
    var d = new Date();
    document.write(formatDate(d));
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

First, you should avoid using `document.write`. Instead, the simplest way is to create a div to write to, like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

You can then add a link to it like this

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = '<a href="http://test.com/'+formatDate(d)+'.html">test</a>';
```

If there is an existing link, for example `<a href="#" id="myLink">test</a>`, you can set the url like this

```
document.getElementById('myLink').href = 'http://test.com/'+formatDate(d)+'.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a *HTMLAnchorElement*

```
function pad2(x) {                        // pad/truncate number to 2 digits
    return ('00' + x).slice(-2);
}

function formatDate(d) {                  // format your date output
    return pad2(d.getMonth() + 1)
         + pad2(d.getDate())
         + pad2(d.getFullYear());
}

function generateLink(url, text) {        // create an <a>
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', url);
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return a;
}

var a = generateLink(
    'http://test.com/' + formatDate(new Date) + '.html',
    'test'
); // HTMLElement <a href="http://test.com/071613.html">test</a>
```

Now you can append this node as desired, e.g. if you wanted to convert back to *String*.

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(a);
```

Or append to `<body>`

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the string with the link URL:

```
var link = "http://www.test.com/"+formatDate(d)+".html";
```

Then alter the `<a>` tag accordingly:

```
document.getElementById('link_id').href = link;
```